# Checking what the input is like then using scanf (C)

Tags: c

So the issue is the user can either give input that is one int, or the user can give an input with three int.  And it all depends on the first input.  Little confusing so here is an example:

```
printf("Please enter input in this format: (-blackwhite | -color) colorvalue");
```

user inputs "-blackwhite 40" so I want to

```
scanf("%s %u", charArray, &int);
```

but user can also input "-color 254 254 254" then I would want to

```
scanf("%s %u %u %u", charArray, &int1, &int2, &int3);
```

How do I go about doing this? Basically verifying the data before I scan it into variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Never* use a naked (unbounded) `%s` in `scanf` unless you control totally the input data format (which you don't here).

Otherwise you open up your code to buffer overruns.

What you should do is to `fgets` a line from `stdin` (since this provides buffer overrun protection) then simply `sscanf` the line.

This has the added bonus that you can `sscanf` your longer four-argument format string and, if it fails, *then* try the two-argument one.

Something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char buffer[200];
    int i1, i2, i3, count;

    printf("Please enter input in format: (-blackwhite | -color) colorvalue: ");
    fflush (stdout);
    if (fgets (buffer, sizeof (buffer), stdin) != NULL) {
        if ((count = sscanf (buffer, " -color %d %d %d", &i1, &i2, &i3)) != 3)
            count = sscanf (buffer, " -blackwhite %d", &i1);
        switch (count) {
            case  1: printf ("blackwhite %d\n", i1);          break;
            case  3: printf ("color %d %d %d\n", i1, i2, i3); break;
            default: printf ("Huh?: %s\n", buffer);           break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: never ever use scanf at all:-) not even think of it.

Comment: Might not even have to try the two argument version.  Since both forms take arguments in the same order, he might be able to just rely on the return values of 4 or 2.  Personally I would do more verification first and avoid the `scanf()` variants all together.

Comment: Actually, while it's dangerous in the wrong hands, it _can_ be used safely. Never with an unbounded `%s` though. Usually best to just stay away from it altogether unless you know its shortcomings _very_ well.

Answer (score 1):

Read the string; compare the string with `-blackwhite` and read a single `int` if it matches; else compare the string with `-color` and read three `int`s if it matches; else bitch at the user.

```
if (scanf("%40s", charArray) == 1)
{
    if (strcmp(charArray, "-blackwhite") == 0)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &int1) == 1)
            ...OK...
        else
            ...error...
    }
    else if (strcmp(charArray, "-color") == 0)
    {
        if (scanf("%d %d %d", &int1, &int2, &int3) == 3)
            ...OK...
        else
            ...error...
    }
    else
        ...error...
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should scan for the words first, test it, then scan for the numbers appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

if your parameter always start with "string input" then followed by N x "integer input", you can write your code using maximum possible number of integer input, as `scanf` will return you number of parameter filled.